# Keras - model.predict(image)[0]

Tags: python, neural-network, deep-learning, keras, predict

I came across the statement below and wasn't sure of what `[0]` means:

```
model.predict(image)[0]
```

So, I did a print out for the above statement once *without* `[0]` and once with `[0]`, as follows:

```
print model.predict(image)

[[ 0.99335432  0.00664574]]

print model.predict(image)[0]

[ 0.99335432  0.00664574]
```

Yes, I can see that the outer square brackets have been removed in the latter case, but still not sure what it means. Any ideas?

Thanks.

Comment: `[0]` is the first element.  In a list of lists, it will be the first list.

Answer (score 2):

`model.predict` return Numpy arrays. Because the API assumes multiple inputs, if you provide a matrix with N images, say dim = (N, H, W, 3), the `model.predict` will return [[ouptut0], [output1], ...[output(N-1)]].

In your case, there was only one image in the inputs, so the input dimension was actually (1, H, W, 3), hence the `model.predict` returned `[[ 0.99335432  0.00664574]]`.

`[0]` returns the first element of whatever `model.predict` returns, hence `[ 0.99335432  0.00664574]`.